# How to extract a filed or sub string from a comma separated records using robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I need to extract AJ out of the given string

```
Test, Mar 1st 2017, AJ, Toggle.
```

Is there any way to get the substring. In robotframework

Comment: How can Regex/Data_extraction relate to `selenium`? Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry about that.. My mistake

Comment: Is this the only string you need to get the data from, or do you need to get it from similar strings? If it's more than one string, what are the rules? Are you certain, for example, that "AJ" will always be between the second and third comma? Is the string you're looking for always "AJ", or is it always just two uppercase characters?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can find a substring Function here:

http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Get%20Substring

Example: ${AJ} = Get Substring ${string} 4 10

With the help of Regex:
http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Get%20Regexp%20Matches

You should be able to extract what you are looking for.

This Regex 
    .*,\s.*\d\d\d\d,\s
(very bad) regex should give you two groups. Group 2, substring 0..2 gives you AJ

Comment: ${Cust}=  Get Regexp Matches  ${logo text}   .*,\s.*\d\d\d\d,\s
  Log To Console  ${Cust} 
 is giving me []

Actually  the data set is dynamic and i need to choose first and last element 
Ex: James and PK 
- James , Mar 1st 2017, PK
- James Jed , Mar 1st 2017, DK
- Rob Dingo , Mar 1st 2017, MK
- Lings Aryan, Mar 1st 2017, LK
- Vipian  , Mar 1st 2017, AJ

Comment: Can you use, split string? with "," as separator [link](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Split%20String)